# InfoBox (getElementById) for each marker – Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3, with InfoBox, in order to style the popups that appear on clicking a marker.

Here's my InfoBox setup:

```
// New InfoWindow
infobox = new InfoBox({
    content: document.getElementById('marker-info'),
    disableAutoPan: false,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
    zIndex: null,
    closeBoxMargin: '10px 9px 12px 0',
    closeBoxURL: siteURL + 'wp-content/themes/bmk-wp-build/img/close-google-popup.png',
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
});
```

I have a Google Map with many markers, which is being set up with Wordpress using ACF and Locations field. All working great but the only issue is the `InfoBox` is outputting the same content for each marker. This is, clearly, to do with this line:

```
content: document.getElementById('marker-info'),
```

Here is my PHP/HTML:

```
<?php while ( $company_query->have_posts() ) : $company_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php $location = get_field('location'); if ( !empty($location) ) : ?>
    <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>" id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
        <div id="marker-info" class="marker-info <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(get_field('logo'), 'full'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Clearly, having an `id` set in the while loop is a bad idea, and stupid, so I can obviously get rid of that, but how would I change:

```
content: document.getElementById('marker-info'),
```

to get each .marker-info for each InfoBox for each marker?

Comment: Can you post your complete JS code? I think the key part is how you're attaching click event handlers to markers and opening the InfoBoxes, but having the complete code would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out with this...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    console.log( $marker.children().html() );

    infobox.open(map,marker);
    infobox.setContent($marker.children().html());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same InfoBox everywhere, and declare it initially without the content option? If I understand right, you can have an event handler for each marker, and set the callback to use the one infobox.
Something like the following:

```
var markers = document.getElementsByClassName('marker');
for( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
         infobox.setContent(this.children[0]);
         infobox.open(map);
    });
}
```

With this, you can probably get rid of using the ID altogether. If you want to keep the ID, I suggest you move setting the ID inside the class name, to appending it to the actual ID inside the PHP code.

Comment: Thanks @LaughDonor. I've added this in but seems to be falling short at the markers.length for statement. I added a console.log for markers and it's showing them all, which is good:

    `var theMarkers = document.getElementsByClassName('marker');
    console.log(theMarkers);
    for ( var i = 0; i < theMarkers.length; i++ ) {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(theMarkers[i], 'click', function() {
         console.log('clicked');
     infobox.setContent(this.children[0]);
     infobox.open(map);
 });
    }`